# Create a small wall with clean topology

Tags: topology

I wan't to go from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

But I want to clean up this part:
[image]

So it's not a face against another face.
What is a fast way to do that?

It doesn't necassary have to be a cleanup after the extrude, not using an extrude at all but get the wanted geometry another way is also fine with me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Manifold* should clean this up automatically, in the extrude operation itself.

(Blender 2.9+)

[image]

Comment: I already clipped the gif before I checked answers :D

Comment: @AllenSimpson Thanks for the contribution! :D Sorry about that.. the countless times my answers have been clobbered by moonboots better and quicker ones. I should have put a gif in myself . My Illustration would have been a  slightly [different way of looking at it](https://imgur.com/a/ShqnpLt), which I'll leave here in the comments for future ref.